# How to show <Skeleton.Image /> only in loading component (Ant Design)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

How can I show or hide the `<Skeleton.Image />` in loading page? I am using the version @4.9.4 of the library "**antd**". I tried with the "**loading**" attribute but the skeleton picture is all the time displayed.

`<Skeleton.Image loading={still_uploading}/>`

https://ant.design/components/skeleton/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

[Skeleton.Image](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/skeleton/Image.tsx) doesn't take in the loading props.

Acceptable Props: 'size' | 'shape' | 'active'

This can be easily solved with conditional loading.

example:

```
{ loading ? <Skeleton.Image /> : null }
```

You need to let still_uploading be a state and change the state once your loading is completed.

```
const App = () => {

  const [ loading, setLoading ] = useState(true);
 

  useEffect(() => {

    setTimeout(() => setLoading(false), 5000);
    //I mock loading with setTimeout,the skeleton disappears in 5 seconds

  },[])

  console.log('loading', loading)
  return (
    <Skeleton loading={loading} />
  )
}
```

see [my codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ujnf4?file=/index.js)

Comment: Yes great! it's exactly what I want! I thought the  `<Skeleton.Image />` took an `loading` parameter too. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The `Skeleton.Image` component doesn't have the property loading, this property is for the `Skeleton component`. In this case you can hide/show the skeleton this way:

```
{still_uploading && <Skeleton.Image/>}
```

These are the properties of Skeleton.Image:

```
export interface SkeletonImageProps extends Omit<SkeletonElementProps, 'size' | 'shape' | 'active'> {
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Yes you have right!